# react-redux re-rendering on componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm using React with Redux with multiple reducers.

I have a component in which I want to fetch data from multiple reducers but each time I make a call to action it re-renders the component (obviously...)

```
async componentDidMount() {
  await this.props.getBooksNamesAsync();
  await this.props.getAuthorsNamesAsync();
  await this.props.getSubscribersAsync();

  this.props.setFilter(
    this.props.book.bookNames,
    this.props.author.authorNames,
    this.props.subscriber.subscriberNames
  );
}
```

- this.props.getBooksNamesAsync() is action on book.
- this.props.getAuthorsNamesAsync() is action on author.
- this.props.getSubscribersAsync() is action on subscriber.

my question is what the best practice for such issue ?

- Is re-rendering the component every action is legitimate ?
- Should I write another action that contains all these actions in one place ? 
  which is quiet code duplication and I prefer to avoid it...

or any other options...

Answer (score 0):

The component rerenders every time there is state change... You can and you should... Here is an example from an old project:

First action creator:

```
export const fetchPosts = () => async (dispatch) => {
  const response = await axios.get('/posts');

  dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_POSTS', payload: response.data });
};
```

Second action creator:

```
export const fetchUser = id => async dispatch => {
  const response = await axios.get(`/users/${id}`);

  dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_USER', payload: response.data });
};
```

And both combined: (*note, it's making use of lodash but you do not have to...*)

```
export const fetchPostsAnUsers = () => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  await dispatch(fetchPosts());
  const userIds = uniq(map(getState().posts, 'userId'));
  userIds.forEach(id => dispatch(fetchUser(id)));
};
```

This was a use case to cut down on the number of calls made to the api but the same holds true for your use case...

Comment: So this is the case of combining 2 actions fetchPosts() and fetchUser(id) in a new action fetchPostsAndUsers().
In addition to that I also need to call another action setFilter() should I combine it also in that action ? isn't too much logic in one action ?

Comment: @kaycee... Yes that's exactly what it is... and that's why I'm using `lodash` to chain and 'clean up the code a little... There are other solutions as well... but if you're working on a team I've found this to be the most 'understandable'...